# React: reading data passed as parameter in history.push

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom, react-16

I am new to react and I am trying to send some data as parameter in `history.push`.

Basically I am calling a method on a button click and inside the method I am calling an api. If I get success response I redirect to other page and I need to pass some data as well.

Below is my code for that:

```
class Login extends Component  {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      enteredName: null,
      enteredPwd: null,
      rescode: null,
      userName: null,
      formatDesc: null,
      userFormat : null,
      success: false,
      responseJson : null,
    };
  }

  state = {
    enteredName: null,
    enteredPwd: null,
    rescode: null,
    userName: null,
    formatDesc: null,
    userFormat : null,
    success: false,
    responseJson : null,
  }
    render=() =>{

        return (
          <Router>
          <div id= "login-page">
            <div className="back-image" style={{height:"100vh"}}>
              <div className="container">
                <form className="form-login" action="index.html">
                  <h2 className="form-login-heading">sign in now</h2>
                  <div className="login-wrap">
                    <label>User ID</label>
                    <input type="text" ref="usrname" className="form-control" placeholder="User ID" autofocus/>
                    <br/>
                    <label>Password</label>
                    <input type="password" ref = "password" className="form-control" placeholder="Password"/>
                    <br/>
                    <a  className="btn btn-theme btn-block" onClick={this.login.bind(this)}><i className="fa fa-lock mr-10"/>SIGN IN</a>
                    <Dialog ref={(component) => { this.dialog = component }} />
                  </div>
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          </Router>
        );

}
login = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  fetch('some url', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify({
      "userId": this.refs.usrname.value,
      "password": this.refs.password.value
    })
  })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
      console.log(`response: ` , responseJson)
      if (responseJson.errorCode === '00') {
        this.setState({ rescode: responseJson.errorCode })
        this.setState({ userName: responseJson.userName })
        this.setState({ formatDesc: responseJson.formatDesc });
        this.setState({userFormat : responseJson.userFormat});
        this.setState({success : true});
        this.setState({responseJson: responseJson});
        this.props.history.push(
          '/Taskactive',
          {
            role_id : this.userFormat,
            userName : this.userName
          }
        );
      }
      else {
        alert("Error Logging in.." + responseJson.errorMsg);
        this.refs.usrname.value = "";
        this.refs.password.value = "";
      }

    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    });

  this.refs.usrname.value = "";
  this.refs.password.value = "";
}
```

so everything is fine till now,but now I need to read the data passed i.e.  **role_id** and **userName** in the next page i.e. **Taskactive**. So how can we read those data in `Taskactive.jsx` ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Okay,after struggling for 4 days and twitching around the answers given by Luna and JupiterAmy, here is what worked for me:

inside the **Login.jsx**

```
this.props.history.push({
          pathname : '/Taskactive',
          state :{
          role_id : responseJson.userFormat,
          userName : this.userName,
          userid: this.refs.usrname.value
          }
          } 
        );
```

and in **Taskactive.jsx**

```
this.props.location.state.role_id
```

Hope this could help somebody in future.

Answer (score 2):

change this

```
this.props.history.push(
          '/Taskactive',
          {
            role_id : this.userFormat,
            userName : this.userName
          }
        );
```

to this:

```
this.props.history.push({
          pathname: '/Taskactive',
          appState: {
            role_id : this.userFormat,
            userName : this.userName
          }
        });
```

And inside the component which you are rendering for path /Taskactive, you can access the values as this.props.location.appState.role_id or this.props.location.appState.userName
You can also change the name of Object(which I have kept as state) to your wish.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Chandrani, Please try it now, there was a syntax mistake. I have updated my answer now.

Comment: i am getting **TypeError: Cannot read property 'role_id' of undefined** when i am trying to read in Taskactive.jsx like  **alert("getroles called "+ this.props.location.appState.role_id);**

Comment: check in your react dev tool whether you have appState available as prop inside location.

Answer (score 0):

if its a component rendered with react-router, the stuff passed are inside component props.

```
console.log(this.props.match.params)
```

from what I see, your router configuration is wrong. Login should be a child of `<Router>`, and shouldn't container router at all.

Example config:

```
<Router>
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={Login} />
    <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
    <Route path="/signup" component={Signup} />
    <Route path="/restore-password" component={RestorePass} />
    <Route path="/forgot-password" component={ForgotPass} />
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

Comment: I tried reading the role_id in Taskactive.jsx like `this.props.role_id` but I am getting undefined in response

Comment: @ChandraniChatterjee no, its not this.props.role_id. its under this.props.match.params. console.log that, and you'll see.

Comment: still getting undefined in console

Comment: @ChandraniChatterjee is your component where you console log rendered by react-router? it shouldn't be a child component for it to work. what exactly do you try to log? try to log exactly what I wrote and check the contents of it

Comment: I am getting undefined in the log and Taskactive.jsx is not child of Login.jsx

Comment: @ChandraniChatterjee I think I see the issue. your configuration is wrong. otherwise this works out of the box. You have Router in Login, and no Route under it. I suggest you reconfigure react-router, but correctly